# API Gravity form, problem with size of JSON

Tags: json, api, curl, php-curl, gravityforms

I have a problem with the Rest API of gravity forms, I use it with the cURL method, I have no problem with, except with the size of the JSON chain, he only give me 10 last entries to the concerned forms, if anyone knows how to ask more entry (or all the entries of the form, that would be perfect but some forms have more than 1000 entry, I think it's too heavy for the JSON link).

```
$CK =ck_12345;
$CS =cs_12345;

$curl = curl_init('https://yoursite.wpserveur.net/wp-json/gf/v2/forms/(form:id)/entries');
curl_setopt_array ($curl, [
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_USERNAME => "$CK",
    CURLOPT_PASSWORD => "$CS",
]);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-type: application/json'));


$data = curl_exec($curl);
if ($data === false) {
    var_dump(curl_error($curl));
}


else {
    $data = json_decode($data, true);
}
curl_close($curl);
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the code you are using to get the entries?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I need to get more entry of the forms, because for the moment, the json chain only give me the 10 last, I think the problem come from the gravity forms API, but I'm not sure. I put update my topic and I put the code in, thanks in advance for you'r help